# How php or any cgi script get executed by a web server?

Tags: php, apache, nginx, webserver, cgi

I want to understand how php or any cgi script get executed by for example apache or nginx

Answer (score 0):

When a route is called on the sever the server passes the parameters and the route to the handler in the cgi_bin folder in the server root for the domain in question.